# See questions recently posed by "high-rep" users

Tags: support, search

Often times I just browse through some of the questions on MSE, and I've noticed that many of the questions posed by lower-rep users (for example, <500) don't show as much effort, aren't as interesting, etc. I found [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10800/how-to-sort-new-questions-by-votes) which gives some direction in ordering recent questions by their votes, but with the activity on the site, there may still be interesting questions with only 2 or 3 votes (or fewer), and I don't have the stamina or interest to go through as many pages as might be necessary. I generally peruse the questions at a leisurely pace, sometimes going through two pages, typically just the few that appear on my screen.

Ideally, an effective way to read some questions of interested/active users would be able to sort out the questions posed by users with at least $x$ reputation. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: There are better proxies for "might be a nontrivial question" than reputation. The one I use is "no answer after 2 days", which is supported by site search: `created:2d answers:0 closed:0`.  Also filtering by tags (`intags:mine`) and ordering the results by votes. Works pretty well.

Comment: @NormalHuman: I definitely agree that is an alternative way to filter; better is just a matter of opinion, though. Sometimes I just like to see questions posed by users with a reputation as high as yourself (for example) because I feel like they *must* be better since someone (much) more knowledgeable than me is asking them (said only partially sarcastically). I respect most, if not all, of the high-rep users and like to know some of the things they think about :) in addition, I would rather help someone genuinely seeking help, and filtering this way can curb most of the "junk" one sees.

Comment: If you are using Chrome or Safari, this may help: [Filter SE questions by votes, views and rep](http://stackapps.com/q/4888). I hope to eventually write my own, adding rep:... parameter to search, but not today.

Comment: Just to throw this out there: I wrote my best question when I was new to the site and had very little rep.  (In fact, I think it was the reason why I joined the site!) Just be careful for what you wish for.

Comment: See also: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12046/filtering-questions-by-ops-reputation

Comment: meta.SE: [Can we filter questions by reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/can-we-filter-questions-by-reputation)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's nothing in the site search capabilities that would allow this, although the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) (SEDE) would allow you to [create a query](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/367747/recent-questions-by-users-with-at-least-min-reputation) to achieve this goal. The only caveat here is that the data in the SEDE is only updated once every week (Sundays at about 03:00 UTC), and so what the query retrieves may not accurately represent the current state of the site.